# fb:comments social plugin as readonly

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

Is it possible to 'configure fb:comments social plugin' to show only comments not allowing new ones? I would like to block old posts on my site to get new comments and I want only show the comments realised in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's only the following options:

```
href - the URL for this Comments plugin. News feed stories on Facebook will link to this URL.
width - the width of the plugin in pixels. Minimum recommended width: 400px.
colorscheme - the color scheme for the plugin. Options: 'light', 'dark'
num_posts - the number of comments to show by default. Default: 10. Minimum: 1
mobile - whether to show the mobile-optimized version. Default: false.
```

But you should be able to write a quick plugin of your own that queries those existing comments and display them.

But I think that would be a nice option to have on the current plugin.  Maybe you should file it with Facebook as an enhancement request.

Comment: Can you show us how to querie those existing comments and display them.

Comment: I am sure the Facebook API has changed much in the last ten years since I posted this.  I am no longer working with the Facebook API.  I would suggest reading thru the latest docs.